# Is there a way to constrain a generic type parameter to generic types?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

Is there a way to constrain a generic type parameter to generic types?

```
//I can constrain a parameter to only object types like this
type GenericType<T extends object> = keyof T ...
//How can I do that for generic types?
type GenericModifier<T extends /* Generic<T> */> = T<...>
//I want to do something like this:
type Distribute<target, type> = type extends infer A ? target<A> : never;
```

Is that possible?

Comment: [Higher kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44875) are not possible yet

Comment: Depending on your use case it may be possible, but you'll need to provide a more detailed / reproducible example. See how this guy explained his problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510438/utility-type-to-filter-generic-types-by-a-static-property

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this

```
/**
 * Forces windening but keeps the structure e.g. ["a","b"] => [string, string]
 * 
*/
type WidenStructure<T> = T extends string
  ? string
  : never | T extends number
  ? number
  : never | T extends bigint
  ? bigint
  : never | T extends boolean
  ? boolean
  : never | unknown extends T
  ? unknown
  : never | T extends any[]
  ? T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? [WidenStructure<Head>, ...WidenStructure<Tail>]
  : []
  :
  | never
  | {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? T[K] : WidenStructure<T[K]>;
  };

type A = WidenStructure<["a", "b"]> // [string, string]


declare const lambda: unique symbol;

/**
 * Declares basic lambda function with an unique symbol
 * to force other interfaces extending from this type
 */
interface Lambda<Args = unknown, Return = unknown> {
  args: Args;
  return: Return;
  [lambda]: never;
}

/**
 * Composes two Lambda type functions and returns a new lambda function
 * JS-equivalent:
 *  const compose = (a,b) => (arg) => a(b(arg))
 *
 */
interface Compose<
  A extends Lambda<WidenStructure<Return<B>>>,
  B extends Lambda<any, Args<A>>,
  I extends Args<B> = Args<B>,
  > extends Lambda {
  args: I;
  inner: Call<B, Args<this>>;
  return: this["inner"] extends Args<A>
  ? Call<A, this["inner"]>
  : never;
}

/**
 * Gets return type value from a Lambda type function
 */
type Call<M extends Lambda, T extends Args<M>> = (M & {
  args: T;
})["return"];

/**
 * Extracts the argument from a lambda function
 */
type Args<M extends Lambda> = M["args"];

type Return<M extends Lambda> = M["return"];

// Test
interface UpperCase extends Lambda<string> {
  return: Uppercase<Args<this>>;
}
interface LowerCase extends Lambda<string> {
  return: Lowercase<Args<this>>;
}

type Test = Call<UpperCase, "asd">; // "ASD"
type ComposeTest = Call<Compose<LowerCase, UpperCase>, "asdasd">; // "asdasd"
```

How does it work:

If you intersect any type with `unknown // e.g. unknown & {} => {}` unknown will be replaced by the other part of the intersection.

So by creating the Lambda interface, we can access the arguments over `this["args"]` and "prefill" our Uppercase with unknown.

When we use the `Call`type  we intersect the argument of our UpperCase-Lambda with some input and replacing the value. Now by accessing the Lambdas return value, we have access to the correct value of the Uppercase type