# Utility type to filter generic types by a static property

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I would like to filter a specific generic type according to a static property. It's easier to show than to explain. I am happy to rephrase the question if anyone can give me a hint how to describe it better (things are quite abstract for a TS novice like me).

```
// My given types
interface ChardataNode {
    type: "Chardata"
    value: string
}
interface ElementNode<TName extends string = string, TChild extends Child = Child> {
    type: "Element"
    name: TName
    children: TChild[]
}
type Child = ElementNode | ChardataNode

// This is what I tried. Unfortunately, the first utility type does not work at all as it doesn't filter out the element children 
type ElementChildren<TParent> = TParent extends ElementNode ? TParent["children"][0]["type"] extends "Element" ? TParent["children"] : never : never
type ElementNames<TElements> = TElements extends ElementNode[] ? TElements[0]["name"] : never

// Setup an example type for testing
type X = ElementNode<"Root", ChardataNode | ElementNode<"Child1", never> | ElementNode<"Child2", never>>

// What I want is: "Child1" | "Child2", but what I get is: never
type Names = ElementNames<ElementChildren<X>>
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkE9QcwSwG4FMB2oAukAOSDOAoOFdJAJwDMBDAYyVAGEALS0gE0vUoDkB7VugN75QIjNiQAuUACImLdp2nDRCSgBsArpNC50pIjHwBfQsTJVaoAKJqkAW1Tpe-ADwAVLpQegkADxIorLg6egagALwh%20igwADSgbkxwaqw%20-qhBDIzJqZFJKQB8oEKiYjhS0jb2jkqlKF7aHg3KItTZKaSoUontrADaALrG%20Jg4WTkR1rYOxM50AD5Z8hzcfEj4%20CAJ2cFwwQDuzOigAJIY%20kisAHSgAKoo5Dyk6Br1JGqQ8eiMdORwpLpQBp0Mk4JgynRWDw8KAUDxjvsngBrUAcVFqNSo3bHKF4FAAcmOfzUJFIoB4wIwPx800coDaOU6aBG4im1WI%20VYTPcAAUWI4ipE3Hymcc-AFMlUZk41qAAPwJEWOPrSBkdVDSAZ9AAMWukoyQmrSEuClVpxGk8sV-OIKrVXI1A1AUhQSGQZJdbrILLGUscngcuHcfuIuEFCRD6GC4oywUjc0GVrckdwOr19QcRs97o2WwAykgXlhUWg-F4sLYIaBHmSSLoDD66AANSbxtYuaQAJR48Ok8TkbBWc1AizbrlkvQAjH3YV7SEVR%20aZePOQAmGeu90FAq5sAAdSOp1A%200oxFAewqnOnI5ka5nACNKYc0WcYIXz7hs96DaAAzDIvGDRBpGnLck2274EAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I came up with this solution:

```
// My given types
interface ChardataNode {
    type: "Chardata"
    value: string
}
interface ElementNode<TName extends string = string, TChild extends Child = Child> {
    type: "Element"
    name: TName
    children: TChild[]
}
type Child = ElementNode | ChardataNode

// The fixed utility types 
type ElementChildren<TParent> = TParent extends ElementNode ? Extract<TParent["children"][0], ElementNode> : never
type ElementNames<TElement> = TElement extends ElementNode ? TElement["name"] : never

// Setup an example type for testing
type X = ElementNode<"Root", ChardataNode | ElementNode<"Child1", never> | ElementNode<"Child2", never>>

// Results in "Child1" | "Child2"
type Names = ElementNames<ElementChildren<X>>
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkE9QcwSwG4FMB2oAukAOSDOAoOFdJAJwDMBDAYyVAGEALS0gE0vUoDkB7VugN75QIjNiQAuUACImLdp2nDRCSgBsArpNC50pIjHwBfQsTJVaoAKJqkAW1Tpe-ADwAVLpQegkADxIorLg6egagALwh%20igwADSgbkxwaqw%20-qhBDIzJqZFJKQB8oEKiYjhS0jb2jkqlKF7aHg3KItTZKaSoUontrADaALrG%20Jg4WTkR1rYOxM50AD5Z8hzcfEj4%20CAJjHTkcL5IqRroyXCYZXigI%20JT1cT5rJ0o7gAKLI5FkW5vT%20hpAZkqjMnGtQAB%20az%20Ug0dCvd7EPrSNo5J7SAZ9AAMA3iQMccyKoCkKCQyFI1zGuNmDVw7kp6E%20CTp-wywTpc3BjOmjkR9QcaMJoGJpI2WwAykh0BosKBKGg-F4sLYLqByDxSBg8CcYuS6AANSZstYuaQAJR4PHQ0nicjYK3Zi0NrlkvQAjFbBSSyEUHVzZkbnTkAEzuoVegoisAmvAaNToYJEGQPN2gRYBlLBnWgTwOYKRNnUlx0h5PFy6grh-BAA)

Answer (score 0):

The part with the array was confusing the compiler.
You have to have a separate step to check for array and a separate step for the array element.

```
interface ChardataNode {
    type: 'Chardata'
    value: string
}
interface ElementNode<TName extends string = string, TChild extends Child = Child> {
    type: 'Element'
    name: TName
    children: TChild[]
}
type Child = ElementNode | ChardataNode

// It's not necessary to check the type of children if you're only interested in the name
type ElementChildren<TParent> = TParent extends ElementNode ? TParent['children'] : never

type ElementName<TElement> = TElement extends ElementNode ? TElement['name'] : never
type ElementsName<TElements> = TElements extends any[] ? ElementName<TElements[0]> : never


// Set up an example type for testing
type X = ElementNode<'Root', ChardataNode | ElementNode<'Child1', never> | ElementNode<'Child2', never>>

// XChildren is an array of ChardataNode | ElementNode<'Child1', never> | ElementNode<'Child2', never>
// but that's not a problem for extracting the name
type XChildren = ElementChildren<X>
// XChildName is 'Child1' | 'Child2'
type XChildName = ElementsName<XChildren>

// Alternative if you're not working with arrays
type XChild = ElementChildren<X>[0]
type XChildNameAlt = ElementName<XChild>


// Utility in case you're looking to extract just children of a certain type
type ElementChildOfType<TParent, TChild> = Extract<ElementChildren<TParent>[0], TChild>
type ElementChildOfTypeElementNode<TParent> = ElementChildOfType<TParent, ElementNode>

// XChildElement is ElementNode<'Child1', never> | ElementNode<'Child2', never>
type XChildElement = ElementChildOfTypeElementNode<X>
```

Tested with v4.7.4

Edit:
You had an unnecessary condition in ElementChildren, which was not necessary for extracting the names.
I've created a separate type for extracting elements of a certain type, if you specifically need that.

Comment: I checked on TS playground, and 'XChildren', 'Names', 'XNames' are all 'never'.

Comment: That's odd. I checked in WebStorm and my version worked well. Maybe if I get time later today I could check what's different on TS playground..

Comment: Hm, I think I found a solution (see my answer). But I am not sure if there are any pitfalls in comparison to your solution.

Comment: @medihack Seems WebStorm is more forgiving than the actual typescript compiler. I just simplified ElementChildren and that fixed it. See the edit.